# ReflectionException: Class HomeController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running php laravel framework 4.2.* with php 5.6. In the apache server, somehow get the error:

ReflectionException (-1)

Class HomeController does not exist

Open:

/var/www/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php

```
    // hand back the results of the functions, which allows functions to be
    // used as resolvers for more fine-tuned resolution of these objects.
    if ($concrete instanceof Closure)
    {
        return $concrete($this, $parameters);
    }

    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);

    // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
```

I have tried composer dump-autoload, but it doesn't work. What is wrong here?

Here is the HomeController

```
<?php

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/shop/sellerfunctions.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/twitter/TweetPHP.php');

class HomeController extends BaseController {
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';
}
```

and routes.php

```
<?php

if($_ENV['LARAVEL_ENV'] != 'local') Route::when('*', 'secure');

Route::get('/','HomeController@showWelcome');
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the HomeController and your routes?

Comment: Edited the question and code added. Thanks

Comment: Laravel 4.2 doesn't require controller namespaces.

Comment: @victorleungtw Does your controller load properly if you remove the `include_once` and `require_once` calls?

Comment: It seems to have some better errors issue than before. I think something wrong with the base path.